# Does a service like Unfuddle + Basecamp + bugtracking exist on the web?

Tags: project-management, bug-trackers, svn

At this moment I have been using multiple services. Unfuddle for SVN and project management via tickets. Basecamp for communication on projects and bugtracker for tracking bugs.

Does a service which is a combination of all above exist on the net?

If someone known about installing all these services on my own server, kindly share it with me. All these means: SVN, Project management and Bugtracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home), even in free plan, can offer

- Any amount of "Spaces" (collection of Assembla tools with tight integration between them)
- *Any amount* of *independent* SVN-repositories (they have 1.8 already) in every *single space*
- Rather good bugtracking
- Messaging for team's communication
- Ability to use external SVN-repositories inside Assembla spaces ("External Subversion" Tool)
- PM-tools like:

  - Milestones in Ticketing tool (tickets can be used as bug- and issue-tracker and planner)
  - Different reports in Tickets tool
  - Stream tab (reflect all space-related activity)
  - Time-tool
  - StandUp reports
- Wiki and Files tools can be just nice addition to other Assembla's possibilities to build full-featured ALM-environment

[Assembla Portfolio](https://www.assembla.com/portfolio) allow you to have all benefits of Spaces, but manage cross-project activity for many teams/many projects case in unified way

Local system on your own server may be (don't ask *me* about price of these Enterprise-level products):

- [Private Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/private-install)
- [UberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn) from WANdisco
- [TeamForge](http://www.collab.net/products/teamforge) from CollabNet

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas come to mind:

- **Agile-oriented, software-specific project management tools**. These have Basecamp-ish project management but software-specific additions (through git or mercurial is more common than svn). Examples: http://blossom.io/, http://sprint.ly/, or for a strong points/results focus, http://pivotaltracker.com/ or https://www.apptrajectory.com/ (Thoughtbot)
- **Syncing between the two**, like with http://www.taskadapter.com. The challenge here is making it feel natural for folks. I've tried this with other services and it hasn't. If you do this, at least make it realtime.
- **Use both**. If you're not committed to switching from Basecamp or Unfuddle (and can live with or want to use both), https://tacoapp.com/manage/basecamp-todos-and-unfuddle-tickets may be a way to decide which service to dive into.